# How to extinguish yourself in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

At full health and with decent armor I got hit by a blaze, and burned to death. All I could do was watching my character burning to death and running around as a living torch.

Obviously, water bucket didn't work, it's the Nether after all. I didn't find any Nether wart yet, so no potions.

How do I go about extinguishing myself or fireproofing myself enough to survive getting set on fire?

Comment: Follow-up question: how to distinguish yourself in the Nether?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't go to the Nether without a healthy stock of [Fire Resistance Potions!](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potions#Potions_with_positive_effects)

[image]

You're right that you can't extinguish yourself, as water can't be placed in the Nether, so you should always keep a stash of these things. Drink them in advance of fighting blazes, but always have a spare one in case you're accidentally on fire.

You can also up your survivability by enchanting some armour with [Fire Protection](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Armor), which will extinguish the flames faster, but not instantly.

Comment: Water can be taken there, you just can't put it down. I still on occasion take a bucket of water with me and dump it out if I get set alight. Then comes the facepalm as it hisses and evaporates away into nothingness...

Comment: I see a problem with this: you need to go to the nether in order to make said potions.

Comment: You can also use cauldrons to get water in the Nether.

Comment: I've noticed being totally satiated helps the surviving chances immensely. Stand calmly in a safe place and let fire and regeneration duke it out. No time for a late meal like when you're on fire!

Comment: The correct answer is modestly hidden in the last paragraph :)

Comment: You can (if you're quick enough) take a cauldron and bucket of water with you. Then if you're on fire, quickly scroll to the cauldron, place it and quickly empty your water in the cauldron. Now you can jump in and get extinguished. This is cutting it pretty close as this takes some time to do.

Comment: How do you make that potion? I've never seen it before.

Comment: An alternate solution is Splash potions of water. Fairly cheap to make, and will extinguish you.

Answer (score 8):

Water can be used in the nether.  Kind of.

Placing a cauldron down, then placing a water bucket in it will allow water to be used to put oneself out, as stepping in the cauldron will remove a bit of water, putting you out.

Answer (score 6):

Get an enchanted apple.  That will give you fire resistance among other things. That is the way to be safe in the nether without having to go there first to get the necessary potion ingredients.

Comment: Brilliant! As someone who plays hardcore mode, this is a perfect way of surviving the Nether until you find a blaze rod. Burning 72 gold ingots is a small price to pay for your only life.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, you just burn to death with serene acceptance. Or flailing, that works too.

On lower difficulties (normal and below, I believe) a fire can go out before it kills you, but you need to be starting with pretty close to full health, which is hard when you were just hit by a fireball.

Ways to survive (or at least have the important things survive):

- Don't take valuables with you until you've got potion-brewing set up. At least then when you die you don't lose much and you can quickly get back there with fresh (crappy) equipment.
- Wear armour enchanted with fire protection and cross your fingers that it'll prevent enough damage to survive until the fire goes out.
- Use cheats to switch to Creative mode.
- Install mods that add items that will help and be craftable before you get potions. ([Death Chest](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v152-risugamis-mods-updated/) in particular would help, but so would healing wands or whatever million different mods are out there.)

That's pretty much it. "Accept and plan for death", "wear magic armour", and "cheat" is the sum of how to deal with burning to death in the Nether without potions.

Answer (score 0):

Use potions. You can use a Potion of Fire Resistance to negate lava/fire damage, or maybe a Potion of Regeneration/Potion of Health to hold off death until you are safe. Golden Apples can do both.

You can try to get somewhere safe and die there/put items in a chest so you can come back after you respawn and get the items.

If you don't mind cheating, type "/gamemode 1" to enter creative mode; flying, invincibility, and infinite items can be achieved with this. If it says "You don't have permission" or something, and your on singleplayer, 
press "Esc" (Escape),
 Click Open to LAN,
 Enable "Allow Cheats",
 and Click "Start LAN world."
 Now type /gamemode 1 and it should work.

Comment: Potion making requires a blaze rod. Blaze rod requires killing a blaze. Killing a blaze is very "burn-prone" activity...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list. **Bold is relevant**

1. **Fire resistance potions**
2. Fire protection armor
3. Powder snow (runs out)
4. **Golden apple (unenchanted has enough regen, and enchanted has fire resistance) (for hardcore)**
5. Water in cauldron (hard to set up and runs out) (impractical for large areas unless you enjoy wasting time *shrug*)
6. Cheats
7. Get out of the nether and use a conventional method
8. **Use a shield to not burn in the first place. SUPER USEFUL**
9. Last resort is a totem

Answer (score -1):

After the Minecraft Wiki:

- If you're on fire and travel through a portal the fire will be extinguished.
- If you stand in an unactivated Nether Portal and light it, you will be instantly teleported (barring load times).

That's not a very portable way, but building a portal near a spawning spot of blazes could be helpful in obtaining the first blaze rod and provide a safe escape route - and then (once you found some nether wart too) you can get to creating potions; while fire resistance will depend on finding and killing magma cubes, you can move around the fortress unmolested with use of a potion of invisibility. (which, outside of nether wart, requires only Overworld ingredients.)

Also, outside of potions, golden apples improve regeneration too, which might help your chance to survive.

Comment: Both of those bullet points are incorrect. Although you can naturally "stop burning" after a while, going through a portal has no effect on this. As for the second point, perhaps that was how portals worked in the past, or perhaps that's just how portals work on SMP, but there is still a loading time even if portals are lit while you are standing in them.

Answer (score -1):

Always bring snow golems (snowmen) to to the nether. They may not stop the blaze's fire, but they will take it's attention away from you.
To make one, place 2 snow blocks vertically and a pumpkin on top.
I don't know if this works. This came off the top of my head when I saw the question.

Comment: Snow Golems take damage in all hot biomes, which the Nether is. They won't last long.

Answer (score -2):

You can dump water at your feet,
Though the water will instantly vaporise to nothing, the split second of existence after it is placed can be used to extinguish oneself.

Or you can use fire resist potions and armour to not burn as much as without.

EDIT: This answer is outdated.

Comment: This will not work in the nether, the water doesn't actually "get placed", it just vaporizes the instant you empty the bucket (the code is instructed to just clear the bucket and play a sound effect, not try to place the water).

Comment: I have succesfully done this in the past, YES the waterblock will evaporate near instantly. But in the tick where it does so, it should still extinguish yourself.
Unless they fixed this in more recent versions.
EDIT: A quick test seems to indicate that they fixed this in one of the previous versions, oh well.